# A table with many records get slow to write and read

Tags: mysql

I have a payment service which has the transactions table on MySQL along with other tables:

```
transactions
-------------
- user_id
- time
- amount
- card_id
```

Every minute hundreds of transactions occur and many users check their app for transaction history. Sometimes, it gets slow to read and write because of high high load.

What would be best approach to deal with this situation? 
I am thinking to move transactions table from MySQL to NoSQL technology (MongoDB or Cassandra). Or can I solve this problem on MySql itself?

### UPDATED

Transactions schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
  `userid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL  
  `store_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL 
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `amount` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL 
  `note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL 
  `status` int(3) DEFAULT NULL 
  `error_mes` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL 
  `card_mask` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_id` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tr_store_id_id_fk` (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Queries:

```
- select * from transactions where userid='xxxx'
- select * from transactions where userid='xxxx' and created_at between 'xxx' and 'xxx'
- select * from transactions where userid='xxxx' and card_id='xxx'
- select * from transactions where userid='xxxx' and store_id='xxx'
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, I forgot to mention )

Comment: Please provide the entire table schema, including indexes as well as the specific query you are trying to tune.  You can certainly solve this problem using MySQL but we need more information.

Comment: @JonathanFite updated

Comment: a) you need to convert the table to InnoDB. b) you need indexes to cover your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>How can you have `PRIMARY KEY(tran_id)` without a column named `tran_id`???</strike>

Your queries need at least one index starting with `user_id` and 3 composite indexes, say:

```
INDEX(userid, created_at)
INDEX(card_id, userid)
INDEX(store_id, userid)
```

Surely most of the fields should be `NOT NULL`??

Bug:  `INT(15)` will *not* hold 15 digits; it will hold only 9 (signed 32-bit numbers).  Suggest `DECIMAL(16,0)` if you are storing credit card numbers.  But then, I would seriously advise hiring a security consultant -- you do *not* want to lose a laptop full of CC numbers; you will be in deep do-do.

Comment: sorry, I changed trans_id to id on transactions scheme in order to be more clear. About CC number, we don't store it. UzCard that works in Uzbekistan has no CC number and payments are confirmed by SMS code. Anyway, I'll talk to security specialist, really appreciate your advice

Comment: in addition, we don't store credit card number in this table, but the mask. 8600******xxx. card number is stored in another table and card_id field is reference to that table.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev - At that point, you may as well store only `8600`, then tack on `***xxx` when you display it.